# В каком году происходит действие в романе "Мастер и Маргарита"?

Tags: литература, история, даты

Всегда интересовало в каком конкретно году происходило действие романа Булгакова?
Есть ли у него какие-то отсылки к дате?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сам Булгаков в черновиках несколько раз менял дату романа. От 1929 в поздних редакциях,
(на предложение Ивана Бездомного отправить Иммануила Канта в Соловки годика на три Воланд отвечает:

> "Водрузить его в Соловки невозможно по той причине, что он уже **сто двадцать пять лет** находится в местах, гораздо более отдалённых от Патриарших прудов, чем Соловки".
>   Черновик 1937 г

А Кант умер в 1804+125 лет = 1929) до 1943, в ранних (Конец Света по Нострадамусу должен был быть в 1943).

> В вечер той страшной субботы, 14 июня 1943 года,  когда потухшее солнце упало за Садовую, а на Патриарших Прудах кровь несчастного Антона Антоновича смешалась с постным маслом на камушке, писательский ресторан «Шалаш Грибоедова» был полным-полон"
>   Черновики 1929-1931 гг

В целом, в романе сочетаются как черты НЭПа (ярый атеизм, дни недели (с 1929 по 1940 7-дневная неделя была отменена), извозчики наряду с автомобилями, будка "Пиво и Воды", шик в ресторане на веранде и др.), так и черты 30-х годов (троллейбусы, война в Испании, паспорта, ТоргСин, Архитекторский съезд и др.). Сюжет описанный в романе, даже в фабульном виде не мог происходить ни в 20-х, ни в 30-х, так как в Сталинскую эпоху, уменьшилась антирелигиозная пропаганда, а в 20-е не было такой власти документа над человеком. Булгаков намерено смешал две эпохи для создания фантасмагорической Москвы вне времени.

В конце приведу, найденную диаграмму, где *частично* представлены события, которые можно соотнести с временем действия романа. Взята [ОТСЮДА](http://litvinovs.net/reflection/master_and_margarita_time_of_action/)

[image]

Comment: Спасибо, Ваш ответ, пожалуй, наиболее полный.

Comment: Не более чем одна из датировок. Прочем - заведомо противоречивая.  
Вообще идея, построенная на том, чтобы просто кого-то опровергнуть (в данном случае - Баркова), очень редко  бывает плодотворной.   
Я удивлен, как сюда еще Фоменку со товарищи не притащили.   
А ведь были таки попытки...  
Кстати, Барков тут  
http://m-bulgakov.narod.ru/master-94.htm#mb_11  
Советую прочитать прежде чем браться за его "опровержения".

Comment: @behemothus, а я никого и не опровергаю. По ссылке есть хорошая диаграмма, подтверждающая мои мысли. Каковы мотивы её автора мне безразлично, факты на диаграмме верные и наглядно показывают хронологический сумбур романа, а больше мне ничего и не нужно. Текст и доводы автора диаграммы, я в своём ответе не использую, выводы у нас также разные.

Comment: Давно уж проехали, но коли вопрос всплыл. Вы зря на себя перевели, я говорил о сомнительности не вашей версии,а именно вашего источника. Он весь посвящен опровержению того, что не достойно таких опровежений.

Comment: @behemothus я оттуда и взял только таблицу, автор статьи вряд ли прочитает это текст, но таблицу он сделал хорошую, несмотря на то, что с его посылом и  выводами я не согласен.

Answer (score 4):

По данным Булгаковской энциклопедии 
(http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enc_bulgakov/80/%C2%AB%D0%9C%D0%90%D0%A1%D0%A2%D0%95%D0%A0)
, действие происходит в 1929 г., когда Пасха приходилась на 5 мая (22 апреля по ст. ст.). 
 Ночь  на 1 мая — это знаменитая Вальпургиева ночь. Прямо после Вальпургиевой ночи Воланд со свитой прибывает в Москву.

Слова Коровьева-Фагота о том, что вот уже тридцать лет камеристка кладет платок Фриде на стол, однозначно указывает на май 1929 г. как на время действия в московских сценах.(Булгаков использовал историю Фриды Келлер, кот. родила мальчика в мае 1899 г., эти записи в его записной книжке)

В варианте 1937 г. на предложение поэта Ивана Бездомного отправить И. Канта годика на три в Соловки Воланд ответствовал, что «водрузить его в Соловки невозможно по той причине, что он уже сто двадцать пять лет находится в местах, гораздо более отдаленных от Патриарших прудов, чем Соловки». Кант скончался 12 февраля 1804 г., так что происходящее на Патриарших оказывается однозначно приурочено к маю 1929 г. В окончательном тексте Булгаков заменил «сто двадцать пять лет» на «с лишком сто лет», чтобы избежать прямого указания на время действия, но косвенные указания на Страстную неделю 1929 г. сохранил.

В редакции , писавшейся в 1929 г., срок, прошедший с момента суда над Иешуа Га-Ноцри и его казни до появления в Москве Воланда со свитой и извлечения из лечебницы Мастера, был определен точно. Здесь Иешуа говорил Пилату, что «тысяча девятьсот лет пройдет, прежде чем выяснится, насколько они наврали, записывая за мной». Появление в Москве Воланда, рассказывающего свой вариант Евангелия, и Мастера, создающего роман о Понтии Пилате, совпадающий с рассказом сатаны, как раз и означает выяснение истины, открытой Иешуа, но искаженной переписчиками. Если московские сцены датированы 1929 г., то срок в 1900 лет должен указывать, что ершалаимские сцены относятся к 29 г. В окончательном тексте М. и М. И в последней редакции М. и М. сохранился ряд косвенных указаний на 29 г. как на дату ершалаимских сцен, а, следовательно, и на 1900-летний промежуток, отделяющий от них московские сцены.

Э. Ренан отмечал, что на пятницу 14 нисана приходилось в 29, 33 и 36 г., которые, следовательно, могли быть годами казни Иисуса. Ренан отвергал 36 г. как возможную дату казни Иисуса, поскольку в этом году еще до Пасхи Понтий Пилат и  Иосиф Каифа лишились своих постов. Возраст же казненного историк оценивал в 37 лет. Га-Ноцри — человек «лет двадцати семи», его проповедническая деятельность продолжается короткое время. Данные обстоятельства, если связать их с евангельской датировкой проповеди Иоанна Крестителя 28 годом (согласно исследованиям историков), указывают на 29 г. как на наиболее вероятное время действия в ершалаимских сценах М. и М.

В финале  в Пасхальную ночь на воскресенье московское и ершалаимское время сливаются воедино. Это одновременно и 5 мая (22 апреля) 1929 г. и 16 нисана 29 г. (точнее, того года иудейского календаря, который приходится на этот год юлианского календаря) — день, когда должен воскреснуть Иешуа Га-Ноцри, и его видят только что прощенный Понтий Пилат, Мастер с Маргаритой и Воланд со своими помощниками. Становится единым пространство московского и ершалаимского миров, причем происходит это в вечном потустороннем мире, где властвует «князь тьмы» Воланд.

Присутствуют в"М. и М." приметы конца эпохи нэпа. Извозчики на улицах еще соседствуют с автомобилями, еще функционируют писательские организации (РАПП, МАПП и т.д.), которые были распущены в 1932 г. и стали образцом для МАССОЛИТа, вполне процветавшего в момент появления Воланда и его товарищей. Т.к. роман писался и корректировался с 1928 по 1940 год, то вместе с вставляемыми эпизодами появлялись события других годов:троллейбусы, например, кот. появились в Москве только в 1934 г., Киевский вокзал и ещё некот. неподходящие под 1929 год приметы времени.

Comment: Это по крайней мере более серьезно и по охватывает (крайней мере - пытается) оценить все более или менее взвешенно.     
   
>действие происходит в 1929 г., когда Пасха приходилась на 5 мая   
  
Беда в том, что в тексте есть указания на конец мая.

Comment: Там есть и другие указания. Это говорит лишь о том,что это художественное время, а не реальное московское.Это же художественный роман со своей целью, иначе был бы не Иешуа, а Христос и главный герой - историческая личность, а не Мастер,в котором мы видим и самого Булгакова,и многих других гонимых, но талантливых писателей.

Comment: Иешуа Га-Ноцри - это (ישוע הנוצרי), Иешуа из Назарета — реконструируемая исходная форма (обратный перевод) евангельского прозвища Иисуса Христа (греч. Ἰησους Ναζαρηνος, Иисус Назарянин). В остальном, согласен с Вами.

Comment: Вот именно - реконструируемая, чтобы был намёк.Евангельские истории используются в худ. произведениях часто, но не стоит там искать библейских образов и привязанности ко времени реальных событий.В "Плахе" Ч.Айтматова" намёк на деяния Христа связан с образом Авдия Каллистратова, а в образе Понтия Пилата главная черта- упоение властью и презрение к гонимым и слабым последователям Христа, а романное время - совмещённое.У каждого своя идея. Булгаков специально совместил приметы разных времён, чтобы мы не привязывали романное время к отдельным событиям, к отдельной реальности.

Comment: Согласен. Поэтому и выбрал ответ Марка Иза. Вам тоже спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Это очень непростой вопрос.
Подробно я здесь писать не буду, это целое исследование, причем результаты у авторов разительно отличаются.

В двух словах так.
В первых редакциях Булгаков датировал действие концом двадцатых годов (напомню, что первые достоверные наброски романа датируются 1928 годом).
В дальнейшем конкретные указания на дату были убраны.
При этом следует иметь в виду, что отдельные элементы привязки к годам перекочевали из первых редакций в последнюю, делая таким образом задачу заведомо противоречивой.

Ко всему прочему появились указания на более позднее время. Так, троллейбус по садовому кольцу был пущен в 1934 г., а Брянский вокзал переименован в Киевский в 1936, и т. д. Если ориентироваться на подобные подробности, то действие никак не могло происходить ранее 1938 г. Вот одна из таких датировок.
http://andrey-android.blogspot.ru/2012/12/blog-post.html

Другие датировки основаны на метео- и астрономических наблюдениях. Они столь же неоднозначны.

Наконец, весьма перспективным представляется календарный подход. В романе упоминается о двенадцати тысячах лун. Вопрос только, как их толковать. У меня есть некоторые соображения по этому поводу, но пока я о них умолчу.